# how to email content of a GUI window in Solaris Env?

Tags: python, email, tkinter

I have made a GUI window using python Tkinter,( the window contains some graphs and charts), I want to email the content of this window through sendmail or any other script, how can I do it? ( I want the charts and graphs in the body of the email)

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague and shows you haven't done any work of your own. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: The problem breaks down into two parts. First you need to capture a screenshot of the window in question, and put it into an image file. Then you need to email that file. Do you actually have to have a program do this, or is this a one-time task that you can do manually? Manually is easier. Try typing `apropos screenshot` and google for your system and "screenshot".

Comment: it is not a one time job, I want to put it in crontab tasks....

Comment: Oh, so you want to capture screenshots with crontab, do you? I'm sure *that's* all very aboveboard. Well, you won't get any help here if you don't have any code of your own to show. Try somewhere else.